# Understanding composer.phar error

Tags: symfony-2.1, composer-php

I'm new with Symfony2 and with composer.phar to install bundles.

Every time I want to install a new bundle I have errors. I don't know if it is my composer.json that is broken or if it is my complete installation of Symfony

```
# php composer.phar require friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle
Please provide a version constraint for the friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle requirement: dev-master
composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove symfony/symfony 2.1.x-dev
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony dev-master, symfony/symfony 2.1.x-dev.
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony 2.2.x-dev, symfony/symfony 2.1.x-dev.
    - don't install symfony/class-loader dev-master|don't install symfony/symfony 2.1.x-dev
    - Installation request for symfony/symfony == 2.1.9999999.9999999-dev -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony 2.1.x-dev.
    - Installation request for symfony/class-loader dev-master -> satisfiable by symfony/class-loader dev-master, symfony/symfony dev-master, symfony/symfony 2.2.x-dev.
```

Is composer trying to tell me that I need to install symfony again ?

Here is my composer.json

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.1.*",
        "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.0.*",
        "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.2.*",
        "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.1.*",
        "symfony/class-loader": "dev-master",
        "friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle": "dev-master",
        "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "dev-master",
        "facebook/php-sdk": "dev-master",
        "friendsofsymfony/facebook-bundle": "dev-master"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web"
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Because of theses errors, I had to install bundles manually (e.g. FOSFacebookBundle) so and I had to update the vendors/composer/autoload_namespaces.php (yeah, I know that's bad)

EDIT2:
When I execure composer.phar update

```
# php composer.phar update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove symfony/symfony 2.1.x-dev
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony 2.1.x-dev
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.4
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.3
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.2
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.1
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.0
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.0-RC2
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.0-RC1
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.0-BETA4
    - Installation request for friendsofsymfony/facebook-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by friendsofsymfony/facebook-bundle dev-master.
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.0-BETA3
    - Installation request for symfony/class-loader dev-master -> satisfiable by symfony/class-loader dev-master, symfony/symfony dev-master, symfony/symfony 2.2.x-dev.
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.0-BETA2
    - friendsofsymfony/facebook-bundle dev-master requires symfony/twig-bundle >=2.1,<2.3-dev -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony 2.1.x-dev, symfony/symfony 2.1.x-dev, symfony/symfony 2.2.x-dev, symfony/symfony v2.1.0, symfony/symfony v2.1.1, symfony/symfony v2.1.2, symfony/symfony v2.1.3, symfony/symfony v2.1.4, symfony/twig-bundle 2.1.x-dev, symfony/twig-bundle 2.2.x-dev, symfony/twig-bundle v2.1.0, symfony/twig-bundle v2.1.1, symfony/twig-bundle v2.1.2, symfony/twig-bundle v2.1.3, symfony/twig-bundle v2.1.4.
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony v2.1.0-BETA1, symfony/symfony 2.2.x-dev.
    - don't install symfony/twig-bundle 2.1.x-dev|don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.0-BETA1
    - don't install symfony/twig-bundle 2.2.x-dev|don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.0-BETA1
    - don't install symfony/twig-bundle v2.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.0-BETA1
    - don't install symfony/twig-bundle v2.1.1|don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.0-BETA1
    - don't install symfony/twig-bundle v2.1.2|don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.0-BETA1
    - don't install symfony/twig-bundle v2.1.3|don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.0-BETA1
    - don't install symfony/twig-bundle v2.1.4|don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.0-BETA1
    - Installation request for symfony/symfony 2.1.* -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony 2.1.x-dev, symfony/symfony v2.1.0, symfony/symfony v2.1.0-BETA1, symfony/symfony v2.1.0-BETA2, symfony/symfony v2.1.0-BETA3, symfony/symfony v2.1.0-BETA4, symfony/symfony v2.1.0-RC1, symfony/symfony v2.1.0-RC2, symfony/symfony v2.1.1, symfony/symfony v2.1.2, symfony/symfony v2.1.3, symfony/symfony v2.1.4.
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does composer.phar update work for you? If so, you should choose a correct version of comment-bundle from packagist.org. Also, is it intentional that comment-bundle is already present in your composer.json file?

Comment: No, does'nt work.. Just posted error above

Comment: Does it work if you remove the comment-bundle from composer.json? If so, you will have to choose a version different from "dev-master". If not, the problem is not with comment-bundle :)

Comment: Does'nt work either.. We are many programmers to work on this project (none of us know symfony)  We all have no idea what happen so  that we can no longer install any bundles. I've tried to change folder permissions, still the same error...

Comment: What if you change `"symfony/symfony": "2.1.*",` with `"symfony/symfony": "2.1.*@stable",`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer!

As simple as it seems (not for me), there was dependency on `symfony/class-loader` that did not references the right version.

So all I had to do is to remove the class-loader and everything's fine.